# Проблема с png прозрачностью в ie6

Tags: html, internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

Это код: http://jsfiddle.net/96YPm/2/

Прозрачность верхней и нижней границы блока сделаны при помощи

```
  -filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader (src='img/block-bottom.png', sizingMethod='scale');
```

Но когда кидает этот фильтр на `.content-block`, то все это превращается в

[image]

На помощь! Уже всю голову сломал.

Comment: а использовать ie8 не пробовали?, нет? так пора уже)))). ie и так мало что поддерживает, а про старую версию я вообще молчу

Comment: Порекомендуйте установить Chrome Frame. и еще рекомендую Boilerplate, однако с png это проблему не решит, но во многом исправляет баги ie.

Answer (score 5):

Вы пользуетесь браузером, созданным в 2001 году. На данный момент браузеру исполнилось десять лет. Даже автомобили в нашей стране меняют чаще. IE6 не удовлетворяет современным стандартам безопасности, скорости и надежности. Для вашей личной безопасности и безопасности ваших данных, мы настоятельно рекомендуем обновить ваш браузер. Установив любой из предложенных ниже браузеров, вы на порядок увеличите скорость открытия страниц, безопасность и вам будут доступны последние интернет-технологии, которые не поддерживаются IE6. (c) какой-то сайт!

Comment: все клево. но нужно чтобы работало на ie6)

Comment: Забудь, вряд ли кто-то даже напрягаться будет ради ie6. Я очень надеюсь что мой ответ будет единственным для данного вопроса.

IE6 - это все оно умерло, к нему микрософт уже обновлений не выпускает, о чем заявил лично.

Comment: @chelovechki ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://omgdroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/jackie-chan-meme.jpg

Comment: http://www.increaseblog.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/dead_ie6.jpg алт=Google хоронит IE.
Согласен со Шреком. Все умирают. VHS умер, флоппи диск умер, таблица безопасных цветов умерла, да и луком со стрелами больше не пользуются. А если кто-то и занимается некрофилией с VHS, например, то он занимается этим с видео-магнитофоном и пиратскими копиями полицейсой академии а не HD-версией аватара.

Comment: Да, конечно, как-то тут был комментарий, что на сайтах с 100500+ посещаемостью процент пользовательй IE6 (или тогда было про IE7) может составлять тысячи. И если у вас есть острая необходимость поддерживать IE6, то во-первых, сделайте для него отдельный CSS-файл с элементарными стилями и не мучайте себя и, наверняка, слабые компьютеры пользователей килограммами js, htc, filter, haslayout, DD_belatedPNG или как его там (ответ на ваш вопрос).

Comment: Во-вторых вы и новичков этому учите, судя по контенту? Зачем? Созреют они еще через год. Это год. Возьмуться за крупный проект с +100500 пользователями еще через год. Это два года. К тому моменту выйдет IE10/IE11, два айфона и три планшета, диабло4, да и вообще, гугл захватят мир. Вы бы лучше сэкономили время в пользу рассмотрения современных проблем с широким диапазоном разрешений, зашкаливающим ppi устройств и т.д. И в конце концов вы сами-то с трудом справляетесь :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [IE PNG Fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/). Чуть подробнее тут: [PNG vs. Internet Explorer](http://habrahabr.ru/post/29201/). Если используете jQuery, то вот [плагин](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/).